# Why can't All Cases be Solved with a Drink?

Tags: beit-din-court, capital-punishment, sotah-secluded-woman

In the case of a סוטה (wayward wife) we have an amazing and miraculous way to figure out if the woman is guilty or innocent. What's so special about the case of סוטה that we have a very special method to get a verdict, versus any other case where punishment is by death?

I understand that in the case of Sotah, there really is no way for anyone to have known (besides the guilty parties). But there are many other cases where it's also quite impossible for anyone to know (e.g. no witnesses by an intentional murder case). Why specifically sotah?

Comment: Heh, I read the title and thought the question was about schnapps and arbitration (_p'shara_) in civil cases.

Comment: @msh210 I was thinking international diplomacy, but same idea.

Answer (score 7):

To show you how important Shalom Bayis is.

Answer (score 2):

There is such a thing as asking the Kohen Gadol, via the Urim VeTumim, to solve tricky questions, but not questions of contention that would otherwise require a Beith Din, just more guidance questions. Still, though, I think the point is to show not only how important Shalom Bayith is, but how incredibly difficult it is to maintain, and how a lack of trust between husband and wife can lead to a wild situation in which only a miracle can answer the question of fidelity. Ultimately, it's up to every couple to communicate with each other and to be honest and keep the lines of communication and trust open at all times.